# How to accept two different languages input in same aspx page

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

I am Creating an administrator page to manage localization key entries in database instead of retrieving from localizedstring.resx. The UI will looks like following

[image]

How can I create a page with two different text to accept two different languages as input?
Please some one help me on this?

**Note**:
 Folks I am not asking a suggestion how to place the controls, I am lacking to accept two different languages as input in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate page with a line, one side english and the other side is chinese, and one submit button. your validations are important here but it is not healthy for users. I recommend put a dropdown list for languages. User will select language, then fills the fields and save. it is more easy for you and for user.

Beign User friendly is always most important :)

Switcing language on client is not possible.

But on server you can use `InputLanguageManager`

like

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
```

this can be usefull for you.

Comment: Yes I agree with you to have dropdown to choose the language. However after choosing the language the text box needs to accept the selected language as input, but still when enter a value in textbox it is showing the english instead of chineese

Comment: So you want to switch system language on dropdown selected changing. on Client, it is not possible.

Comment: TMoon the InputLanguageManager component is related to WPF, however I am expecting in ASP.net